# Sprite Image in Canvas not displaying correctly (distorted)

Tags: unity

I have a problem with displaying images in my Canvas, as they're not displaying exactly like the imported image.

In the image below, the sprite on the left is how it looks when it's imported. The sprite on the right is how it looks in the canvas. Notice that some of the pixels have incorrect colours, like the lighter pink in the center of the staff's top is gone, the eyeball is a darker shade, some of the colouration under the hood is wrong, and other errors.

( The sprite is just a test I took from somewhere else, not what I intend to use as a final product. )

[image]

The project is 3D (going for a 2.5D look with billboard sprites) set to 384x224 resolution, orthographic camera size of 3.5, no anistropic textures, no anti-aliasing.

Is there some setting I missed somewhere to ensure that images display 100% exact like the source sprite when used in the Canvas?

EDIT
Sprite in the Inspector
(Seems to also not be correct)

EDIT
Added entire inspector
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely scenarios that would make this happen: Wrong import settings, 3D lights affecting the supposedly 2D object, non-pixel perfect canvas.

I'd say, try checking the box that says Pixel Perfect on the canvas. That should fix it. If not, check your import settings, make sure there's no compression. If that's not the problem then it should be the lights affecting your 2D object (not sure if it's even possible) try removing all lighting from scene.

Report back with your findings, I'm curious to see what the problem is.

Edit: Problem is the compression.

Compression on Normal Quality:
[image]
Compression on High Quality:
[image]
Compression on None:
[image]

Comment: The sprite import settings are:
Pixels per Unit = 32
Generate Mip-maps = False
Filter Mode = Point (no filter)

Canvas is set to Pixel Perfect.

I turned off all lights (just one, which was elsewhere in the scene and shouldn't have been reaching the image in the canvas) and nothing changed. I'm assuming there's a way to make sure UI is not being affected by world lighting?

Comment: It should already be free of world lighting or any other lighting but that was just a last chance kinda thing. Can you post an image of the sprite in the inspector? (Click on the sprite in the assets and get a prnt scr) you can just add it to the question details. I'll try replicating your problem on a separate window now.

Comment: I added the sprite inspector image to the question above.

It looks wrong in the inspector, with the same problems as mentioned.

But if I double-click the sprite in the Assets folder it's in, the image it displays in my external image viewer is correct (It's the image on the left above).

Comment: I was trying to get a screenshot more along the lines of what I posted. Anyway, compare yours to mine if that helps.

Comment: Editted the question with a view of the entire Unity window with the inspector.

I don't have the same options you do when importing a Sprite, so not sure how to proceed on this.

Comment: Also accidentally edited the wrong comment (yours) and deleted your image by mistake, as I thought I was overwriting my own. Oops.

Comment: Np, it just came as a suggestion. I think I've figured it out (I hope). Try changing Pixels per Unit to 1 (or something low like 3 or 4) and then scale the model down.

Comment: If this also doesn't work, then Unity itself must be doing something to the model when it is importing. What's the file extension? (Try editing with Gimp and saving as a png file, Unity seems to love that).

Comment: It's not a model, it's just an image in the Canvas.

Anyways, I changed the import setting on the sprite to 1 PPU, but no change in how it looked.

As for the file extension, it's a PNG.

I don't think it's a problem with the importing process, since the PNG in my Assets folder in the project is correct. It just seems wrong when displayed in the Canvas and Inspector.

Comment: Can you upload the png file or give me the link where you got it from? (So I can check if it's the file or something else)

Comment: Uploaded the image to imgur here:
http://i.imgur.com/kT2Xf8L.png

Comment: Alright, I managed to replicate the problem. In my screen where you see max size and compression, it says normal quality. If I leave it like that, your problem occurs but if I change it to high quality, the problem goes away. I think you need to press the override button and select different compression methods (I'm using Unity 5.5 and it might be a bit different but it should still be close). If you do "none" as the compression it should give the highest quality.

Comment: Well, I'm going to bed for tonight. Hopefully, you have fixed your problem and I think I managed to be of some help :P If I see another reply in the morning I'll look into it further :)

Comment: That fixed it!

I totally did not notice those options underneath Override. So my version of unity doesn't have High, Normal, and None, but it did have a 16-bit option which removed the loss during the import. Thanks!